# Getting 'Rscript: Bad address' error when CRAN build my package on windows platforms

Tags: r, cran, rscript

I'm the maintener of the rtkore package and I'm experimenting an error during the installation on
the `r-devel-windows-x86_64` and the `r-release-windows-x86_64` platform. When trying to compile I get

```
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"D:/RCompile/recent/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/projects/ -I../inst/include/ -DIS_RTKPP_LIB  -DSTKUSELAPACK -I'D:/RCompile/CRANpkg/lib/4.3/Rcpp/include'   -I"d:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c fastRand.cpp -o fastRand.o
/bin/sh: line 1: /x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin/g++: Bad address
```

A search indicate that the problem is from the "D:" (not sure it is the correct answer)

In all case, I cannot modify these path as there given by the CRAN mechanism of compilation.

Can you give me some hints about the problem and how to solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: You should ask there: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel